# spawn/generate existing components dynamically in Angular 11

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular9, angular2-components

I'm doing an web application that is supposed to work like the contacts app that we have in our phones:

1. Register contact info (name, email, number)
2. Click on save Button
3. **List is updated immediately (here is my problem)**

So I have a *list.component* (a grey mat-card) and a *contact.component*, (an orange mat-card).

I want to spawn a new *contact.component* inside of the *list.component*, and destroy it when the user select the delete button.
[image: It looks like this now]

The data is passing fine, but I don't know how to add a new existing component inside another.

Comment: Thanks for the description of the issue you are having. Without seeing any code though, it is difficult to provide you with direction. Maybe you could create a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy) project with the code you currently have?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is difficult to assess your issue without code; consider adding a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the contacts inside a public array and then iterate over it inside the list-component:

```
  <list-component>
<ng-container *ngFor="let contact of contactArray"> 
<contact-component></contact-component>
 </ng-container>
</list-component>
```

When the user adds another contact, you can push it to the contactArray and the additional contact-component will appear